# Program Flow explanation in C

Tags: c, recursion

New progammer here.

Can anyone help me understand the flow of below program? I have mentioned my understanding in below section. Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Objective here is to print 1 to n without using loops using C language. I was able to get this done using goto function but stumbled upon the below solution/code and ran into doubts. Any help is appreciated.

**Code**

```
// Prints numbers from 1 to n
void printNos(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n > 0) {
        printNos(n - 1);
        printf("%d ", n);
    }
    return;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int n = 10;
    printNos(n);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding...

1. In the 'main' part (mentioned as Driver code), we define an int by the name of 'n' and give it a value of 10
2. in the next line we are calling the function 'printNos' and passing the value of of n i.e 10 as an argument
3. Now program jumps to 'printNos' function and recives the value of n as 10
4. in the 'printNos' function program reaches the if condition and checks if 10 is greater than 0
5. If condition turns out to be true and now goes in the body of if function
   ****This is where i need help from****
6. Here as per my understanding we are again calling the 'printNos' function with an argument of 10-1 that is 9
7. As per my understanding this goes in self loop with a new parameter of n-1 i.e 8 then 7 then 6 and so on till n is greater than 0

question 1 - how does the printf piece get executed?
question 2 - what is the use of getchar() in main body?

Comment: What do you mean with "how does the printf piece gets executed?"  It's a function call like every other, it's just happens to be defined in the standard library.  `getchar()` is just used to require user input when program is about to terminate.  In programming there is often little cost of trying things out so in this case remove the `getchar()` and see how the changed program behaves.

Comment: At step 5, a new invocation of the function `printNos()` is made with a different value for `n` — one less than the previous call.  This is "recursion" (search for it).  The first new copy has `n` equal to `9`; it makes another recursive call, …  When the recursive calls return, the value passed into the function is printed.  The recursion stops when `n` is `0`; the function returns without printing anything, then the calling function prints `1` and returns, then the function that called that prints `2` and returns, …

Comment: One way to build intuition of a recursive function is to trace it, i.e print how it's called and when it exits.  In `main()` consider changing the type of `n` from `int` to `unsigned int` to match the argument type.

Comment: Notice how the `printf("%d ", n);` comes after the recursive call to `printNos(n - 1);`? Your function calls itself again before `printf` is reached. That will occur until `n == 0` when the last function call returns and then the first `printf()` is reached, executed and that call returns -- to the next prior `printf()`, ... You can think of this manner of recursive function as **winding in** until the **exit condition** is satisfied, and then all function calls **unwind** hitting the `printf()` as the function calls unwind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word you're missing here is "recursive". `printNos()` is a *recursive* function, because it calls itself. As is necessary to avoid infinite recursion, it has a condition that permits it to *not* call itself, which is when `n == 0`. So what happens is that it builds up a stack of calls to itself, decrementing `n` each time until it gets to zero. Then it starts returning from each of those calls, which is when each `printf()` gets executed, in reverse order from how they were stacked. The values of `n` go on the stack 10, 9, ..., 1, and then come off the stack and are printed 1, 2, ..., 10.

As for the `getchar()`, that pauses the program until a character is provided as input. I have no idea why that's in there.

Comment: `getchar()` is for code run by an IDE, where the IDE opens a terminal window, runs the code, and closes the window immediately after the program finishes. For a program that run in milliseconds, the user is left wondering why nothing happened.

Comment: People that simply build from the command line don't have that problem `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That would be me.

Comment: thank you @MarkAdler, this helped. I have not reached the concept of stack so far in my learning course but did some research and was able to understand.

Comment: The stack is simply where a function call saves the location to return to. The `return` statement in a function (or simply reaching the end — same thing) needs to know where it was called from in order to get back. It finds that information on the stack. In the old days, the Fortran language would simply store that address in the called function. However that only works once, and prevents the use of, wait for it, _recursion_! So a stack is required for recursive functions.

Comment: The stack is also used as a convenient way to make space for local variables in a function, where that space is automatically released upon return.

Answer (score 1):

This program replaces [iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Computing) by [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#In_computer_science). An iteration commonly uses some loop construct, including `goto` jumping backwards.

The secret behind recursion is that the computer remembers where a function was called from. In C, you can additionally look at all parameters as local variables. So each call of `printNos()` has its own `n`.

> question 1 - how does the printf piece gets executed?

Let's do a fast-forward until `n` is 2...

1. `printNos()` is called with `n` equal to 2. The conditional is true, so `printNos()` is recursively called with `n - 1`, which is 1.
2. On entry, the conditional is still true. So `printNos()` is again called, this time with `n - 1` equal to 0.
3. This time, the conditional is false. Therefore, `printNos()` simply returns. (BTW, the `return` is not necessary as last statement.)
4. On return, the `printNos()` called with `n` equal to 1 continues. Now `printf()` gets called with `n` and prints "1 ".
5. After returning from `printf()`, this `printNos()` also returns, there is nothing more to do.
6. Now the outermost `printNos()` continues with its `printf()`. As its `n` is 2, `printf()` prints "2 ".
7. And again, this outermost `printNos()` returns.

[image]

> question 2 - what is the use of getchar () in main body?

This is seen sometimes in beginner's code, because they use an IDE that opens a command window to run such programs. This window closes as soon as the program quits, and all output is gone. Using `getchar()` lets the program wait until the user enters a potentially empty line.

The call has usually a second effect. On many systems all output of `printf()` is not immediately output, but buffered. `getchar()` flushes the output buffer. And as `getchar()` commonly echoes its input, the <kbd>enter</kbd> breaks the output line, too.

However, if you run this program in a separate command window, the output buffer is flushed on the exit of the program at latest.

If the program would output a new-line `'\n'` at one or more occasions, the output buffer will also commonly be flushed.

Comment: thank you @the busybee , this helped. I have not reached the concept of stack so far in my learning course but did some research and was able to understand.

Comment: @mm25www You don't even need the concept of a stack to understand the abstract working. However, it helps to understand _how_ the computer is able to track its call hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` function gets called as if statement turns out to be true.

As for `getchar()`, it is used to read a single character from the input stream. Also, here `getchar()` holds the output screen as that will fade immediately.

Comment: I think op understands the if statement.  What they are missing is that `n -1` is passed by copy so each function modifies a different (stack) variable.   You trace the call, or expand the program to use a set of non-recursive functions perhaps to show how the recursive program is equivalent?

Comment: yes he has confusion in recursion maybe

Answer (score -1):

This is a rather trivial example of *recursive functions*, a mechanism in C which should almost certainly be avoided in some 99% of all use cases. It is slow, it takes up lots of memory, it is dangerous and it is hard to read.

C beginners tend to spend ridiculous amounts of time understanding this mostly useless mechanism, which could have been better spent on things like learning proper program design and learning to avoid bad practices (such as using recursion). The so-called rationale for using recursion in school is always "learning" but nobody can typically explain what you should use it for once you've learnt it.

The key to learning it, if you must, is to use excessive printing. Modify your function like this:

```
void printNos(unsigned int n)
{
    printf("calling printNos, n=%d, ",n);
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("%d is > 0\n", n);

        printNos(n - 1);
        printf("This is the function with n==%d finishing... ", n);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d is <= 0\n", n);
    }
    printf("n==%d function done\n",n);
}
```

And you'll notice that this spawns 11 overlapping function calls, no function finishing until we've reached the negative < 0 condition:

```
calling printNos, n=10, 10 is > 0
calling printNos, n=9, 9 is > 0
calling printNos, n=8, 8 is > 0
calling printNos, n=7, 7 is > 0
calling printNos, n=6, 6 is > 0
calling printNos, n=5, 5 is > 0
calling printNos, n=4, 4 is > 0
calling printNos, n=3, 3 is > 0
calling printNos, n=2, 2 is > 0
calling printNos, n=1, 1 is > 0
calling printNos, n=0, 0 is <= 0
n==0 function done
This is the function with n==1 finishing... n==1 function done
This is the function with n==2 finishing... n==2 function done
This is the function with n==3 finishing... n==3 function done
This is the function with n==4 finishing... n==4 function done
This is the function with n==5 finishing... n==5 function done
This is the function with n==6 finishing... n==6 function done
This is the function with n==7 finishing... n==7 function done
This is the function with n==8 finishing... n==8 function done
This is the function with n==9 finishing... n==9 function done
This is the function with n==10 finishing... n==10 function done
```

This means that we spawn 11 function call overheads which get stored on the stack, bloating it and bringing it closer to stack overflow - a severe bug which is common when recursion is used.

Therefore it is very bad practice to write recursive calls in a manner that cannot be optimized. A compiler's optimizer can often *unroll* recursion and replace it with a loop internally, but only if the recursive call is done at the end ("at the tail") of the function, a so-called *tail-call*. Or otherwise we risk bloating the stack and get needlessly slow performance.

Summary:

- Beginners should never use recursion. There is no obvious reason why they need to learn it.
- Others should most often never use recursion either, save for a few exceptional cases in algorithm theory when implementing certain search/sort/bst algorithms. And then only as a last resort.
- When you use recursion as a last resort, it should be of the tail-call variety and you need to inspect the disassembly of the optimized code to see that the compiler actually managed to unroll the recursion.